# ExecutorService.shutdownNow() setting variables as null

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice

I'm creating an `ExecutorService` with

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

and I add `Runnables` with

```
executor.execute(runnable)
```

I have a `java.sql.Connection` instance that is created somewhere inside the runnable implementation and is closed inside a `finally` statement.

This works perfectly until I call `executor.shutdownNow()`. When I do this, the connection gets its value as null, i.e., with the inspector I see `connection = null`. 
If I stop the executor with the `shutdown()` method everything works perfectly.

I've been searching and reading (even java's source code) but cannot understand what may be causing this.

I tried to catch an `InterrupedException` but apparently theres is none being thrown

Comment: no, the executor is _not_ setting this to null.  some logic path in your code is most likely happening which you don't expect.  show some example code.  note that when you use `shutdownNow()`, _some tasks may never be executed_!

Comment: also note that `shutdownNow()` interrupts any running tasks, which could cause something to be thrown inside your finally block before the Connection is created.

Comment: Shouldn't the shutdownNow() gracefully terminate the running tasks? That was my understanding... And actually, I don't see any exception being thrown and I'm logging every single exception that is thrown

Comment: you have yet to show any relevant code, so it's hard to give much in the way of more specific pointers.  not sure what you mean about "gracefully terminating the running tasks", but `shutdownNow()` will certainly interrupt them (using standard java thread interrupts).

Comment: It is not necessarily that an interrupted thread throws an exception and quits. It all depends on interrupted code, it may catch InterruptedException, log it, null the connection field ...

Comment: @MiguelRibeiro You are getting lots of valuable information.  Edit your post to include the source for the `Runnable` implenentation if you don't want to have the question closed.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know anything about the unwanted side effets that `shutdownNow()` has for you...
Normally, a `shutdown()` should be enough to cause the `ExecutorService` to reject new jobs and the worker threads to finish the remaining jobs in the queue. Unfortunately, there seems to be a gap between `shutdown()` (which will let all previously submitted jobs complete) and `shutdownNow()` (which will try to interrupt currently executing jobs). There should an inbetween `shutdownAlmostNow()` that lets the ES finish their current jobs, but return those still waiting like `shutdownNow()`.

---

If you use a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, you could call `shutdown()`, get the job queue and drain it, so there will be no new jobs accepted and the old jobs are taken off the queue. Then you could await termination of the current jobs.